# Change views exposed filter value only on page reload

Tags: views, 8, forms, ajax

Is there a clean way to alter a View exposed filter field, but only on page reload and not each time you submit the exposed filters form ?

---

**Example**

I have a View with exposed filters. When a user is loading this View, I want to change the value of an exposed filter field, depending on a cookie value.

I've managed to make it work with the `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter` function.

```
function HOOK_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-MY-VIEW') {
        $cookies = \Drupal::request()->cookies->all();
        if (isset($cookies['MY_COOKIE'])) {
            $form['MY_FIELD']['#value'] = $cookies['MY_COOKIE'];
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is : if the user manually change the exposed filter and submit the form, the value is getting back to the first one because the hook_form_alter is getting called again.

Here is a video : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSRLQ.jpg

---

**Poor solution**

I've found a solution, but it doesn't looks like a good one. I've found out that when the hook_form_alter is getting called by a submit, there is a new entry (`'a' => ''`) in the UserInput array that you can find by calling `$form_state->getUserInput()`.

First load :

```
[
    'MY_FIELD' => 'All',
    '...' => '...'
]
```

After submit :

```
[
    'MY_FIELD' => 'New value',
    'a' => '',
    '...' => '...'
]
```

So now I can use the following to change the field value only on the page load :

```
if (isset($cookies['MY_COOKIE']) && !array_key_exists('a', $form_state->getUserInput())) {
    $form['MY_FIELD']['#value'] = $cookies['MY_COOKIE'];
}
```

*But I'm not even sure it is fully functional, is there a better way to do it ?*

---

**Clean solution**

Thank's to @NoSssweat, here's a cleaner solution :

```
function MODULE_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view) {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    $is_ajax = $request->isXmlHttpRequest();
    if (!$is_ajax) {
        $cookies = \Drupal::request()->cookies->all();
        if (isset($cookies['MY_COOKIE'])) {
            $view->setExposedInput(['MY_FIELD' => [$cookies['MY_COOKIE'] => $cookies['MY_COOKIE']]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @NoSssweat The `hook_views_pre_build` is working but I've the same problem : each time I submit the exposed filter form, the field value is getting back to the previous value.

Comment: @NoSssweat Just added a video link to show you : https://imgur.com/EmVha6e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just added a video link to show you : [imgur.com/EmVha6e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSRLQ.jpg)

You just need to add a conditional to check if it's not ajax

```
   $request = \Drupal::request();
   $is_ajax = $request->isXmlHttpRequest();
   if (!$is_ajax) {
     // code that sets the filter initial value
   }
```

<sub>Credit: [How can I detect AJAX request inside Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54296/how-can-i-detect-ajax-request-inside-drupal)</sub>

Comment: That's it ! I've finally used the `hook_views_pre_build` function. With the request check, it seems the best solution, a lot cleaner than the one I was using. Thank you !