# Why a form doesn't keep the value created during construction

Tags: forms, ajax

Here is a form using DI for `$this->entity_type_manager`

There is also a radio-button with Ajax (I have added the code as it is maybe the reason of my problem)

```
class myForm extends FormBase {

  private ?EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager=NULL;

  public function __construct(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager) {

    $this->entity_type_manager=$entity_type_manager;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
    );
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // keep the value in $form_state to be used in submit
    $form_state->set('entity_type_manager', $this->entity_type_manager);
    ...
    // Maybe the Ajax component is the problem
    $form['container'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      'my_radio' => [
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#options' => ["option1","option2"],
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => $type_of_bo,
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxGetInvestmentHandler'],
          'wrapper' => 'ajax-wrapper',
          'event' => 'click input',
        ],
      ],
      ...
    ];
  }

  static public function ajaxGetInvestmentHandler(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['container'];
  }
  
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // $this->entity_type_manager is NULL
    // $form_state->get('entity_type_manager') is also NULL
    ...
  }

  ...
  
}
```

As you can see in the `submit`, `$this->entity_type_manager` is NULL and `$form_state->get('entity_type_manager')` is also NULL.

What is wrong?

Comment: "As you can see" - how can we see this? There isn't any reason why it should be null, how are you determining it is?

Comment: Sorry to not be clear enough. I meant that I have made some tests on those values and they are NULL (as showed by the somments in the submit). I agree this should not be NULL but it is... maybe it is coming from the AJAX?

Comment: Based on the code shown, it's not possible for `$this->entity_type_manager` to be NULL. The submitForm function cannot be called without instantiating the form, and the form requires the variable be passed to it to construct the form. That's why I'm asking how you diagnosed it to be NULL.

Comment: $this->entity_type_manager is also NULL in the validate function...

Comment: Because you're setting it to null... `$entity_type_manager=NULL;`

Comment: If I don't set it to NULL as a default value, I got `$entity_type_manager must not be accessed before initialization`

Comment: Then that's a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As you can see in the submit, $this->entity_type_manager is NULL*

You need to declare the service property `protected`. Private properties can't be restored. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-for-a-form#s-considerations-for-dependency-injection

*.. and $form_state->get('entity_type_manager') is also NULL*

The form_state is not cached between the first form build and the submit request. See [buildForm: how differentiate between page reload and ajax callback?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/303888/buildform-how-differentiate-between-page-reload-and-ajax-callback). And when you run the form build in later Ajax requests you overwrite the form state value with NULL.

Comment: This is magic. You save my day!!!