Form storage values are not persisted when validation fails
I need to persist some data in a form even when validation fails. The code below (taken from the examples module) works - except for the first time the form is rendered and submitted (and the validation fails).

This question is similar, but the answer with most upvotes does not solve my issue.
I have tried not setting the foo value in validateForm(), but the issue remains.
I would like to avoid using TempStore, SessionStorage or similar hacks.
<?php

namespace Drupal\form_api_example\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements the SimpleForm form controller.
 *
 * This example demonstrates a simple form with a single text input element. We
 * extend FormBase which is the simplest form base class used in Drupal.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase
 */
class SimpleForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * Build the simple form.
   *
   * A build form method constructs an array that defines how markup and
   * other form elements are included in an HTML form.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   Default form array structure.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   Object containing current form state.
   *
   * @return array
   *   The render array defining the elements of the form.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    if ( ! $form_state->has('foo') ) {
      $text = $this->t('foo not set');
      $form_state->set('foo', 'bar');
    }
    else {
      $text = $this->t('Foo was set to @foo', ['@foo' => $form_state->get('foo')]);
    }

    $form['description'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $text,
    ];

    $form['title'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Title must be at least 5 characters in length.'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    // Group submit handlers in an actions element with a key of "actions" so
    // that it gets styled correctly, and so that other modules may add actions
    // to the form. This is not required, but is convention.
    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];

    // Add a submit button that handles the submission of the form.
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Getter method for Form ID.
   *
   * The form ID is used in implementations of hook_form_alter() to allow other
   * modules to alter the render array built by this form controller. It must be
   * unique site wide. It normally starts with the providing module's name.
   *
   * @return string
   *   The unique ID of the form defined by this class.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'form_api_example_simple_form';
  }

  /**
   * Implements form validation.
   *
   * The validateForm method is the default method called to validate input on
   * a form.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   The render array of the currently built form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   Object describing the current state of the form.
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $title = $form_state->getValue('title');
    if (strlen($title) < 5) {
      // Set an error for the form element with a key of "title".
      $form_state->setErrorByName('title', $this->t('The title must be at least 5 characters long.'));
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    $form_state->set('foo', 'barbar');
  }

  /**
   * Implements a form submit handler.
   *
   * The submitForm method is the default method called for any submit elements.
   *
   * @param array $form
   *   The render array of the currently built form.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   Object describing the current state of the form.
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /*
     * This would normally be replaced by code that actually does something
     * with the title.
     */
    $title = $form_state->getValue('title');
    $this->messenger()->addMessage($this->t('You specified a title of %title.', ['%title' => $title]));
  }

}



It should all work as expected - potentially having your  $form_state->setRebuild(); is interferring with the form APIs automated rebuilding when the error is set. Have you tried removing that/putting it in an else?

Removing the $form_state->setRebuild(); makes no difference. I don't know what you mean by "putting it in an else"? And finally - when you write it should work as expected - do you agree that it should be possible to save the variable in the form storage also in this scenario? Thanks :)

Try use $form['foo'] = ['#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => 'bar'] instead of $form_state->set in your buildForm. Remove form_state->setRebuild() too I don't think it's necessary.

@Beebee I think I could make that work if I get the raw value with $form_state->getUserInput() - but is this really the cleanest way of doing it? (In other words - $form_state->getValue('foo') does not work).

It does work, but you have to wait for the right time. If the value is not there, you are still in the initial form build, which runs multiple times in different requests and has to produce the same result. More background info https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/303888/buildform-how-differentiate-between-page-reload-and-ajax-callback

@benjamin_dk I can't really see how $form_state->getValue() won't "work". Are you sure the hidden 'foo' field is being rendered and submitted with the form? In that case it should be always available from getValue otherwise you're doing something wrong.

@Beebee I have made this video where I try to demo the issue https://youtu.be/0C5ns6trOdk. The code I use can be found here https://gist.github.com/benjamin-dk/f3af232e83694d127f1a3657a50f12bb

Thanks for making the video! I can see that there's something definitely strange happening which I'm not aware of. Reading the docs for the hidden element, perhaps you should use #default_value instead of #value? But in any case this is beyond my knowledge, hope you get to the bottom of this!
